# Decoding the error from an api duplicate status update?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, json

I'm having a problem with processing the error caught when posting a duplicate status...

```
try {
    $twitter->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => $tweet));
} catch (EpiTwitterForbiddenException $e) {
    $msg = json_decode($e->getMessage());

//wp_die('Error: ' . $msg . ''); // Server errors out
wp_die('Error: ' . $e . ''); // Returns code in lower segment

    if ($msg->error != 'Status is a duplicate.') {

    //throw $e; // Disabled to prevent
    }
}
```

The first wp_die errors out and the server crashes
The second wp_die returns:

```
Exception 'EpiTwitterForbiddenException' with message '{"errors":[{"code":187,"message":"Status is a duplicate"}]}' in /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/libs/api/EpiTwitter.php:265 Stack trace: #0 /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/libs/api/EpiTwitter.php(226): EpiTwitterException::raise(Object(EpiCurlManager), false) #1 /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/libs/api/EpiTwitter.php(127): EpiTwitterJson->__get('response') #2 /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/libs/api/EpiTwitter.php(109): EpiTwitter->request('POST', '/statuses/updat...', Array) #3 /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/download.php(109): EpiTwitter->__call('post_statusesUp...', Array) #4 /home5/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/download/download.php(109): EpiTwitter->post_statusesUpdate(Array) #5 {main}
```

How am I supposed to decode that to get the error from within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
// adding "true" as second argument forces json_decode to return an associative array
$msg = json_decode($e->getMessage(), true);
// print out the array
wp_die("error: " . print_r($msg, true));
```

Comment: The output in which I get is: `Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 187 [message] => Status is a duplicate ) ) )`
To match that with the if statement in my original post how would that be acheived?